# How to programmatically import a Shapefile into Oracle DB using Java?

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools, oracle-dbms, hibernate-spatial

What's the best approach to import a user uploaded shapefile into an Oracle DB? The dbf, shx and shp files of the Shapefile come in a ZIP Archive.

Currently, we unzip programatically and then parse the dbf, shx and shp files manually using custom Java and the GeoTools library. From this we build SQL Strings to create the table and insert the values. This works, but seems cumbersome given the complexity of shapefiles.

I thought that there must be an easier way of just using some kind of Java library to which we pass the shapefile. The library should just take care of all the shapefile import stuff.

However, I do not find any GeoTools method for simply importing a Shapefile into a Oracle DB. I only found [this Oracle Java Program](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_shapefile_converter.htm#SPATL1428), but no tutorials on how to use this as part of a java based web portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple operation in GeoTools, once you have read in the [Shapefile](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html) you will have a FeatureCollection which you just need to write to an [Oracle Datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/oracle.html).

I have an example of how to write a Database (mysql and postgis are the examples included) [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/5735).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Spatial comes with a collection of Java APIs, and one of them lets you read shapefiles. That API is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPAJV/toc.htm. Look for the `oracle.spatial.util package`, specifically class `ShapefileFeatureJGeom`. It uses lower level classes that perform the actual reading of the shapefile (`DBFReaderJGeom` and `ShapefileFeatureJGeom`). That API is used by Mapbuilder and is also used by the command-line program you indicate (`SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature`).